# If statement inside setted function

Tags: php

How to edit  already setted function inside `()` if I want inside that function if statement

```
<?php
$a = 1;


function writeMsg($x) {
  echo $x;
}

writeMsg( 

Hello, 

if ($a == 1) {
echo "men";
} else {
echo "women";
}
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to prepare the message first then write message.

```
<?php
$a = 1;

function writeMsg($x) {
  echo $x;
}

$message = 'Hello, '. ( $a == 1 ? 'men' : 'women');
writeMsg($message);
```